# ヘルプのDuplicate、Closedの部分が仕様と違う

Tags: バグ, 完了, 日本語, ヘルプ

[場所](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates)

> 質問を重複としてマークするのは質問のクローズ手続きの一部ですが、質問が重複としてクローズされた場合は、タイトルには「[Closed]」ではなく「[Duplicate]」が追加されます。

日本語版の場合、`Closed`はクローズ済み、`Duplicate`は重複だと思います。
そのような仕様なのでヘルプも揃えたほうが分かりやすいと思います。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

適用しました。確認宜しくお願いします。

https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates